# Fatal Exception: Receiver not registered: com.salesforce.marketingcloud.notifications.NotificationOpenActivity

Tags: sfdcmobilesdk-android

I have experienced a serie of crashes with my **Android** app which use the **MarketingCloudSDK**.

"Nearly all" (for now I see only **Android 12+**) the devices crashes, I suspect it occured when the user clicks on the notification)

The version I use (**8.1.4**):
 `implementation(com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:8.1.4")`

The full stack trace :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.salesforce.marketingcloud.notifications.NotificationOpenActivity$a@998d28
       at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1568)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1800)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:781)
       at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.notifications.NotificationOpenActivity$a.onReceive(:2)
       at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:319)
       at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:127)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8168)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1037)
```

The SDK initialisation :

```
SFMCSdk.configure(
  context = this,
   config = SFMCSdkModuleConfig.build {
           pushModuleConfig = MarketingCloudConfig.builder()
             .setApplicationId(BuildConfig.MarketingCloudAppId)
             .setAccessToken(BuildConfig.MarketingCloudAccessToken)
             .setSenderId(BuildConfig.MarketingCloudSenderId)
             .setMarketingCloudServerUrl(BuildConfig.MarketingCloudServerUrl)
             .setNotificationCustomizationOptions(
                 NotificationCustomizationOptions.create(
                       R.mipmap.ic_launcher_foreground,
                       { context, notificationMessage ->
                           val url = notificationMessage.url
                           when {
                             url.isNullOrEmpty() ->
                                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                   context,
                                   UrlNoRedirectIntentRequestCode,
                                   Intent(context, MyActivity::class.java),
                                   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or. PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE,
                                )
                              else ->
                                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                  context,
                                   UrlRedirectIntentRequestCode,
                                   Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)),
                                   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE,
                                )
                              }
                            },
                            { context, _ ->
                                NotificationManager.createDefaultNotificationChannel(context)
                            },
                        ),
                    )
                    .build(this@MyApp)
            },
        )
```

I am missing something ?

Thanks in avdvance for your help

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue, and I suspect it was introduced in version 8.1.4 of the SDK. However, that version is not even listed under https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/#releases. It was at least available on January 12, as per the last updated date of https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/repository/com/salesforce/marketingcloud/marketingcloudsdk/maven-metadata.xml, but other than that it's difficult to know anything about the release, since it's not documented.

Comment: My bad, I misread the date in the linked Maven Metadata document. It says December 1, 2023, not January 12 2024. (20231201000000)

Comment: The metadata document has now been updated to reflect when 8.1.4 was _supposed_ to have been released, on January 30.

Comment: Hi, I reverted to the 8.1.3 and no problem since.
I suppose it was an issue with the version 8.1.4, I will wait for the next one before updating